# Defining operator symbols

Tags: symbols, amsmath

I want to replace the circle in the symbol `\circledast` by a square. But i did not find the right command. It seems that the packages `stmaryrd` would help. But the package usually re-defines other basic symbols which is not desired.

The `amssymb` package seems not define such a symbol. Is there anyone know how to define some command like `\boxdast` or `\squaredast`? Or how to avoid other changes by introducing packages that already defines `\boxdast` or `\squaredast`?

Comment: you can use a package like [savesym](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/savesym) or [noconflict](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/noconflict) to avoid unwanted redefining of symbols by `stmaryrd`

Comment: As far as I know, `stmaryrd` redefines *no* symbol in the standard stock. Can you show an example?

Comment: As egreg says `stmaryrd` does not clash with standard latex symbols nor `amssymb`.  `stmaryrd` has `\boxast` already.  Alternatively `mathabx` has `\boxasterisk` and  `\boxcoasterisk` and `\bigboxasterisk`

Comment: @egreg I got one mistake; you are correct, `stmaryrd` does not casue any confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example composes `\boxast` from `\Box` and `*` and only needs package `amssymb` because of `\Box`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\boxast}{%
  \mathbin{% as \boxplus and \boxtimes
    \mathpalette\@boxit{*}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@boxit}[2]{%
  % #1: math style (\displaystyle, \textstyle, ...)
  % #2: symbol to be boxed that is centered around the math axis
  \sbox0{$\m@th#1\Box$}%
  % Manual correction for font bounding boxes:
  \ifx#1\displaystyle \ht0=\dimexpr\ht0+.05ex\relax \fi
  \ifx#1\textstyle \ht0=\dimexpr\ht0+.05ex\relax \fi
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle \ht0=\dimexpr\ht0+.04ex\relax \fi
  \ifx#1\scriptscriptstyle \ht0=\dimexpr\ht0+.065ex\relax \fi
  \sbox2{$#1\vcenter{}$}% \ht2 is positionn of math axis
  \rlap{%
    \hbox to \wd0{%
      \hfill
      \raisebox{%
        \dimexpr.5\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax-\ht2\relax
      }{$\m@th#1#2$}%
      \hfill
    }%
  }%
  \Box
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$A \boxplus B \boxast C^{D \boxast E^{F \boxast G}}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- Macro `\@boxit` assumes that the symbol to be boxed is centered around the math axis as some of the typical boxed symbols are (plus, minus, times, ast). Then the symbol is placed in the middle of the box. (There might be tiny deviations because glyph side bearings are not taken into account.)
- The reason for `\mathpalette` is to get the actual math style in order to match the size of the symbol according to the current math style.
- `\m@th` removes `\mathsurround`, because it should add space around the formula, not within, if `\mathsurround` is set.
- **Update:** The font bounding box of `\Box` is a little too small in the height, therefore I have added a manual correction.

  The following file shows the font bounding boxes for `\Box`, first the unmodified font bounding box (red), then the corrected bounding box (green). (The larger width 
  of the font bounding box
  does not matter, because the white space left and right seems to be the same and the symbol remains centered.)

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{color}

  \begin{document}
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}
  \newcommand*{\test}[2]{%
    \fbox{\color{red}$\csname #1style\endcsname\Box$}%
    \fbox{\color{green}%
      $\csname #1style\endcsname\Box$%
      \vphantom{\raisebox{#2}{$\csname #1style\endcsname\Box$}}%
    }%
  }
  \newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
    \fbox{\color{blue}$\csname #1style\endcsname\Box$}%
  }
  \test{display}
  \test{text}
  \test{script}
  \test{scriptscript}
  \end{document}
  ```

> [image: Font bounding boxes]

Comment: It appears to me that the asterisks in the last box is not centered, i.e. in `F \boxast G`. Any idea what is causing that? A very nice solution though :-)

Comment: @Mythio: There was an calculation error: `-\dp0` instead of `+\dp0`, but `\dp0` is `0.0pt`, thus this had no impact on the result. The font bounding boxes however, are not entirely correct, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Tikz to accomplish this.

Something like the following, which declares the command `\boxast`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}

\newcommand*\boxast{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node [rectangle,scale=1,draw] {$\ast$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
And it looks like: $\boxast$
\end{document}
```

Which gives this as result:

[image]

I left the `scale` option in there, because you can use that the tweak the size a bit. For instance, try `scale=0.7` to make it approximately the same height as the text. It depends a bit on how you want to  use the symbol exactly.

Comment: Why `\ensuremath` in the command? Also it doesn't take an argument. And you don't need PGF package if you have TikZ and you don't need `positioning` for this too :)

Comment: @percusse; Thank you :-) The trouble of reusing code that I reused myself before for other commands. I've changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way (without tikz) that is quite brief (shown with super- and supersuperscript).  The size of the box symbol will be scaled to the current size of a capital "B", regardless of what script mode you are in.

To explain the use of the packages, the asterisk is inset into the box via the `stackengine` package.  The bottom (dead zone) of the box is clipped with `\addvbuffer` of the `verbatimbox` package, and the resulting symbol is scaled to the size of a capital B by way of the `scalerel` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newsavebox\boxastcontent
\sbox\boxastcontent{\addvbuffer[0ex -.4ex]{\topinset{*}{$\Box$}{.25ex}{}}}
\def\boxast{\scalerel*{\usebox{\boxastcontent}}{B}}
\begin{document}
\(A\boxast B^{A\boxast B^{A \boxast B}}\)
\end{document}
```

[image]